# How to block unused URLs in Wordpress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have made a very simple website (2 Pages) using Wordpress Waterlava theme. My website contains many URLs, for which I haven't created a page, but still they open up in the web browser.

e.g.

<*my website URL*>/author/user/

<*my website URL*>/category/uncategorized/

To block such URLs, I tried to comment template getter function names in array named $tag_templates defined inside template-loader.php. But this solution did not work. Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **uncategorized** is a default category that could not be deleted. If you do not have any posts inside this category, the URL will not display anywhere in your website, because empty categories are hidden by default (99% in all themes settings). Now, if you want to stop these URLs from search engines, you may add them to robots.txt file via a reg exp Disallow. Last but not least, the author URLs

```
<my website URL>/author/user/
```

does appear, when you display the author's name inside your blog posts. You may see sometimes:

```
written by **author**
```

This **author name** is a **link**, that users of your website could click and see all the posts of the specific author.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will make the necessary changes in the robots,txt. But, is it possible that if someone enters "<my website URL>/category/uncategorized/" into the browser's address bar, then the visitor should be redirected to my 404.html page?

Comment: Yes, if you are familiar with redirects yhrough .htaccess file you could add a redirect throught this. Otherwise, you could add a plugin like Redirection (https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) and add the URLs you want. If my answer solve your issue, please accept the answer to help others.